# How to show this best in order to explain a generic concept?

Tags: architecture, web

I have a bunch of projects which have a similar architecture...

```
A----1      Y
 \  / \     /
  \/   \   /
 /  \   \ /
B---2----X----Z, etc, etc
\  /    /
  \    /
 /  \ /
C----3
```

(sorry about the bad ascii art)

- there can be multiple A, B, C (generally one, but may be more) in each project (measurement/control devices)
- each of which will use one of 1, 2, 3 (communciations technologies)
- to communicate with X (databse server)
- which serves Y, Z, etc (browser based apps)

I am not very good at displaying things graphically, so am wondering if someone can suggest:

1. something static- a generic way to display this in documentation (I tried using nice symbols to reflect the actual system components, but is because visually messy)
2. something dynamic - some way to show it on a Web Site (perhaps having just one item for each of the A, B, C and 1, 2, 3 columns and having the images fade into each other).

Should I do this automatically, or as a result of user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this for static (sorry for the bad ascii art ;)

```
--------------       -------------            --- Client 1
| Components |       | Comms     |           /
|            |-------| Channel   | --- Server --- Client 2
| A, B, C    |       | 1, 2 or 3 |           \
--------------       -------------            --- Client X
```

**Update**: "Dynamic for a website" is a bit generic. Depends on what you mean by that. You could generate SVG graphics or some fancy HTML5 + JavaScript - maybe the tools mentioned in the other answers support output like that?

Comment: +1 Yes, that's sort of what I have gone for. I would have liked to have used cisons, but there are so many A,B,C ...Z and 1, 2, 3 ...   any thoughts on the dynamic aspect, for a web site?

Answer (score 3):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is usually my first choice. The [Gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) has lots of examples, and the [Dot](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) language is simple and straight-forward.

A thought on the layout: Maybe the communications channel should be expressed as an interface on the database server rather than a node of its own. As ChrisWue suggests, a three (or four) layered graph with Component -> Database server -> Clients. The [switch](http://www.graphviz.org/content/switch) example of Graphviz seems pretty close.

Comment: +1 for graphviz (I like it), buit how to diaagram it without looking too messy?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to visualise data in some fashion: http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

Comment: +1 thanks. Somewhat reminiscent of graphgviz, but a nice tool